# Getting string from json object not working

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using `gson` library to get the json from an http request. 
Everything works fine, except the part where I compare the string I received from the request. Even if the string are exactly the same, for some reason `string.equals` method fails. And as output it prints always `different dates`.

What is the reason for this behaviour? What am I missing here?

```
 BufferedReader br;
    try{
        String url = "http://date.jsontest.com/";
        URL request_url = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)request_url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        if (200 == conn.getResponseCode()){
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            String jsonLine = "";
            String line ;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonLine += line;
            }

            JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);
            JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();

            try{
                String result = jobject.get("date").toString();
                System.out.println("res: " + result);

                if(result.equals("05-29-2017"))
                    System.out.println("Same date");
                else
                    System.out.println("different date");
            }
            catch (NullPointerException ex){ }
        }
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException ex){} 
    catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Comment: What does it print? **System.out.println("res: " + result);**

Comment: @YanKhonski it prints `05-29-2017`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String result = jobject.get("date").toString();
```

The above line returns String representation of `date`, i.e. with quotes around it : `"05-29-2017"` and that's why `equals` method returns `false` (`"\"05-29-2017\"".equals("05-29-2017")` will be `false` due to double quotes in the start and end)

If you want the actual value, you need to use `getAsString` method, e.g. following should work:

```
String result = jobject.get("date").getAsString();
if(result.equals("05-29-2017"))
    System.out.println("Same date");
else
    System.out.println("different date");
```